# How do you put a \tag at the end of an equation containing a \choice in an iopart document?

Tags: formatting, overleaf

I'm trying to create a report with an equation that is either one thing, under one condition, or something else, under a different condition. I would also like to include an equation tag in parentheses at the end of the line.

My current code for testing of this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\newcases{iopcases}{\tqs}
 {$\m@th\displaystyle##$\hfil}
 {##\hfil}
 {\lbrace}
 {.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
j = n\mu E - D\nabla n,
\end{eqnarray}


\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)=\begin{iopcases}  1 & ABC \\ 2 & uvw \end{iopcases}
\end{eqnarray}

\noindent Text between the two equations

\[f(x)=\begin{iopcases} 1 & ABC \\  & 2 & uvw \end{iopcases}%\]

\tag{(4)} \\



\end{document}
```

Available here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/csndrqmksbbb.

This code outputs the following document:

[image: image_1]

The first equation is an example from earlier in the paper that worked correctly, the second has a tag with parentheses at the right indentation level, however, has a tag included within the data for the curly brace, and the third equation is perfect except that the tag is at the wrong indentation level.

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having worked on this a bit more, I found that the code provided by other answers does work, however, the formatting isn't necessarily consistent with the rest of the IOP style.

The version that works properly to achieve this with a single tag on the right hand ride of the page is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\iopartcases\cases

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    f(x)=\iopartcases{1 & abc \\ 0 & uvw}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This is entirely consistent with other formatting in the IOP style and only has a single tag on the right to label the equation.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded `iopart.cls` from the site and the trick you use for loading `amsmath` doesn't work. Anyway, in order to solve your problem you can use `cases` with some workarounds.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
%\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname\relax
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname\relax
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcases{iopcases}{\tqs}
 {$\m@th\displaystyle##$\hfil}
 {##\hfil}
 {\lbrace}
 {.}
\newenvironment{iopnumcases}{%
  \newcommand\@unnc@casecr[1][\z@skip]{\cr \noalign{\vskip ##1}}%
  \let\\\@unnc@casecr
  \patchcmd{\numcases}{\quad}{\qquad}{}{}%
  \openup\jot
  \numcases
}{\endnumcases}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
j = n\mu E - D\nabla n,
\\
f(x)=\begin{iopcases}  1 & ABC \\ 2 & uvw \end{iopcases}
\end{gather}
Text between the two equations
\begin{iopnumcases}{f(x)=}
  1 & ABC \\
  2 & uvw
\end{iopnumcases}

\end{document}
```

Never use `eqnarray`: it's buggy. Also, don't use consecutive displays, but, in this case, `gather`. Never leave a blank line before displays. In your case, no blank line should be used.

For tagging both cases, you can use the newly defined `iopnumcases`.

[image]